# How to stop the influence of a curve modifier for part of a mesh after having animated along it?

Tags: animation, modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a long thin constant width mesh (a bit like a long train, but it actually looks like a wall) that moves along a curve using the curve modifier. And when the mesh has reached the end of the curve it stops (having the bent shape of the curve). Now I want the end of my mesh to animate straigt out into a 90 degree angle. As if the last "train wagon" was pulled off the track, but still attached to the rest of the train. Without having the front of the "train" loose it's bent shape from the modifier. 
But when I animate the end part of the mesh it is still affected by the curve modifier and gets deformed. It basically looks like the last wagon gets a little banana shaped and maybe also a little wider in one end. I want it to keep it´s width and be able to straighten it out and continue the animation using only the end of the mesh.

I have tried animating the visibility of the curve modifier as gandalf3 suggested. Didn't know you could do that. Really cool feature (for those out there that do not know how to - try right clicking on the eye icon or pressing I while hoovering the mouse pointer over the eye). 
But it hasn't worked out for me as I hoped. It seems like animating the curve modifiers visibility is the path to the solution but there must be some part of the puzzle missing.
When visibility is turned off the mesh jumps sideways to the position it really is located at hadn't it been for the modifiers influence. 
In order for me to be able to turn off visibility only for the last part of the mesh, as I want the beginning of it to stay affected by the curve modifier, I also tried dividing the mesh into vertex groups. And just animate the modifier visibility on one of the vertex groups. But this doesn't work as I had hoped either, the vertex group I animate visibility on still jumps out of place. And separating the mesh into two parented objects doesn't help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In other words, you want to disable the curve modifier after a certain amount of time? If that is what you want, you could keyframe the visibility settings at the top of the modifier.